# python subprocess Popen crashed but I did not call it directly

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am porting all my python program in Eclipse and pydev to a new computer. 
Then I wrote the following statement in my program:

```
        outText = check_output("adb devices").decode('utf-8')
```

In the old computer, this was good. 
But in the new computer, it created a bug and python dumped the following.

```
  File "C:\Users\FARN\Documents\LINUX\realtime\PRGM\TaaDPlayground\src\moduleAndroid\testingModuleAndroid.py", line 82, in getDevice
    outText = check_output("adb devices").decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
  File "C:\Users\FARN\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 420, in new_CreateProcess
    return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(app_name, patch_arg_str_win(cmd_line), *args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
```

In the old computer, I used python 3.4.3.
In the new one, I tried both python 3.4.3 and 3.6. 
The bug still persists.
What is the problem?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is a user error. The cause for the FileNotFoundError is that `adb` is not installed. Maybe you were running on Linux before and downgraded?

BTW `check_output()` is just a very thin layer around `Popen()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Indeed this is the correction.